# Else If conditional with logical operators not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm having trouble setting animations when the browser window is a different size, in other words, making animations responsive.

In the code below, only the first If block works. The else If block doesn't work, there´s no syntax errors.

Thanks for the help.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var firstAnimation = function() {
  $('#in-view').delay(300).css("display","block").animate({          
      opacity:1,
      right: -150
  },'slow');
};

var h4Animation = function() {
$('#hr1').delay(500).animate({
    width: '60%'
},'200');
};


if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200 ) {
       h4Animation();
       firstAnimation();       
   } else if ($(window).width() >= 769) { 
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
          h4Animation();
          firstAnimation();            
       }
   }
}   
});
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code, so can you post a jsfiddle to show us what is exactly your problem?

Comment: after indenting your code correctly - are you sure the elseif is correctly located? I seems like the elseif should be on the first level - tied to the `window.height` instead of the second level.

Comment: As described in my comment below. I forgot to close the first condition. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else is in the wrong place:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200 ) {
       h4Animation();
       firstAnimation();       
   } else if ($(window).width() >= 769) { // how can window width be both <= 768 and >= 769?
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
          h4Animation();
          firstAnimation();            
       }
   }
}   
});
```

Instead:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200 ) {
       h4Animation();
       firstAnimation();       
   }
}
else if ($(window).width() >= 769) { // the condition isn't really necessary since if it is not <= 768 it will be >= 768
       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
          h4Animation();
          firstAnimation();            
       }
   }
}   
});
```

Comment: Since i've made changes to the code earlier, i forgot to close the first condition. The problem is now solved. By the way, i thought the browser would confuse the same value of 768 for less than or greater than so i've added a pixel but it is redundant afterall. Thanks for the help MikeS